# R convert query output to table

Tags: r, sql-server-2008-r2, dataframe, rodbc

New to R programming.
I have a simple sql server query whose output looks like this :

```
EFFECTIVE_DATE  NumberOfUser
 2015-07-01         564
 2015-07-02         433
 2015-07-03         306
 2015-07-04         50
```

Here's how I issue the query:

```
 barData <- sqlQuery(sqlCon, 
                     "select EFFECTIVE_DATE,COUNT(USER_ID) as NumberOfUser from UserTable where start_dt between '20150701' AND '20150704' group by EFFECTIVE_DATE order by EFFECTIVE_DATE")
```

Now I am running this query from R and want to do a barplot on this. What is the best way to do that?

Also how do i convert any query result to a data.table with which I can do barplot? When I try `table(myList)`, it is showing a different format altogether.

Comment: no actual code as such..i have just stored the query output in a variable and now i want to plot a bar chart from that.
barData<- sqlQuery(sqlCon,"select EFFECTIVE_DATE,COUNT(USER_ID) as NumberOfUser
from UserTable where start_dt between '20150701' AND '20150704'
                        group by EFFECTIVE_DATE order by EFFECTIVE_DATE")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help on `sqlQuery` (I don't use ODBC generally) says *"On success, a data frame…"* is returned. That would mean you should be able to do something like:

```
barplot(barData$NumberOfUser, names.arg=barData$EFFECTIVE_DATE,
        xlab="Effective Date", ylab="Number of Users")
```

[image]

But posting the output of a `dput(barData)` into your question would really make it easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) Can you explain the conversion of list to data.table

Comment: can we set las=2 in barplot()

Comment: Well, it's not really a `list` (per se). it's a `data.frame`. do `class(barData)` and you'll see it is indeed (most likely…since I don't have the data here) a `data.frame`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you used the `sqldf` package in R, an sql query of the form `SELECT EFFECTIVE_DATE, NUM_OF_USERS FROM USERTABLE` is executed using the `sqldf(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,...)` statement:

```
sql_string <- "select
          effective_date
         , num_of_users
          from USRTABLE"

user_dates <- sqldf(join_string,stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

resulting in a data.frame object. Use the **data.table** package to convert the data frame into a data table:

```
user_dates <- as.data.table(user_dates)
```

A new data frame, `user_dates`, will be created using the sqldf statement. The sqldf statement, at minimum, requires a character string with the SQL operation to be performed. The `stringsAsFactors` argument will force categorical variables to have the class character rather than factor.

**EDIT** : Sincere apologies, didn't see you stating the package name in the question. In case you decide to use the sqldf package, creating a bar plot is a straightforward call to the `barplot(height, ...)` function:

```
barplot(user_dates$num_of_users,names.arg=user_dates$effective_date)
```

Also please note that the result of the sqlQuery on successful execution is a data frame and not a list:

> On success, a data frame (possibly with 0 rows) or character string.  On error, if
>   errors = TRUE
>   a character vector of error message(s), otherwise an invisible integer error code
>   -1
>   (general, call
>   odbcGetErrMsg
>   for details) or
>   -2
>   (no data, which may not be an error as some SQL statements do
>   return no data).

Comment: i used RODBC and when i give a typeOf(resultSet), it shows list.

Comment: last time I checked `sqlQuery` wasn't in the `sqldf` package, so this is a bad assumption

Comment: ok..sow how do i convert the this list to a table from which i can actually do  barplot? Thanks

Comment: then when i say typeOf(queryOutput), why it says list?

Comment: 'class(object)' is the function you should use; it gives the abstract type of the object. typeof(object) gives the type of the object from R's point of view, i.e., how its stored in memory. [ http://rfunction.com/archives/770 ]

Comment: Thansks..one more doubt
can we set las=2 in barplot()?

Comment: 'las' is a numerical graphical parameter that takes on discrete values in the set {0,1,2,3} and represents the style of axis labels, each value denoting a unique style and orientation. The value 2 sets the labels to be displayed always perpendicular to the axis. More info can be found by typing '?par' on the command line.